# Too many objects match the primary key oracle.jbo.Key

Tags: java, oracle, view, jdeveloper, composite-primary-key

I am getting this error: `Too many objects match the primary key oracle.jbo.Key` when I tried to search in some view object where the `primary key` is consists of more than one filed.

**Use-case:**

In `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3` I have `Entity object` called `someTable` this table has three fileds `A,B and C` where the `primary key` is consist of tow filed `A and B`.

I created tow different `View object` from `someTable` enity object which are `someTableVO1` and `someTableVO2`. Filed `A` in the view object `somtableVO1` is a `List Of Value(LOV)` and the data is coming form filed `A` in the `someTableVO2`.

In application I have a searching page which contain a drop down list for filed `A` in `somTableVO1`. Based on some conditions the drop down list values is not static. The value of the drop down list is changeable based on a `select` query executed on `someTableVO1` and it is based on the thried filed `C` which is **NOT** part of the `primary key`.

The page shows the drop down list with the correct values. But, I have a `ValeChangeListener` method which will be activated when ever the user select some value form the drop down list.

**The problem is:**

The error `Too many objects match the primary key` is occur when ever I am executing this method.

**Assumption:**

I think that the problem is with the multiple fields for the primary key. of curse there is a duplication in part of the `primary key` ( i.e in one filed `A` or `B`) but the combination of `A` and `B` is always unique.

**Notes:**

**1.** I check the query by running it in `SQL Developer` and it is not showing any duplicate values.

**2.** I did not attach code, because I think the problem is not about (how to do) it is about (what to do).

I hope the idea is clear

Comment: Your primary key isn't unique.  Make it so.

Comment: the combination of the tow fields is always unique as mention in the question. Can you clarify...

Comment: Looks like Oracle disagrees with you.

Comment: OK,
 
I find out the root cause of the problem but I could not resolve it yet.
 
it has nothing to do with the multiple filed of primary key. Instead, it is about the recursive List Of Value (LOV). In my case the attribute A is a list of value that its values coming form view object form the same entity object that has the same data and the same primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem Solved.***

My aim was to show one filed which is `A` form `someTableVO1` as a list of value and I was trying to achieve that by creating list of value form the same `Entity object`. I figure out that this was a wrong approach (*Correct me if I am worng*). to achieve that in `ADF` technology I should do the following:

1. Simply drag and drop the view object from the `Data Controls` to the page.
2. List of options will appear asking how you would like to show the view object like (Form, Graph,Table,Single selection,....).

3.Select `Single Selection` -> `ADF one Selection`

4.Select the attribute(s) you want to be shown to user as a list of values.

That's it...